# How to change the width of label once after its frame has been set? and to get the width of NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilabel, xcode4.5

hope you are doing good.

I am setting a label and adjusting its frame ..

```
UILabel *mylabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    mylabel.Text=@"This is my label";
    mylabel.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,200,21);
```

now if I change the Label's text from any string set by me like this

```
NSString *mystring=@"This is my first string that is to be assigned to my label dynamilcally";
mylabel.Text=mystring;
mylabel.frame.size.width=mystring.length;
```

but nothing happens. The width of the label remains 200, as I set while at the time of initialisation.

This will also need to get the **width** of the **mystring** . How to get that?

Thank in anticipation for helping me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[myLabel sizeToFit]` if you need it on one line. For multiple line labels you can use `NSString`'s `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` function to get size of your string and use it to modify your label's height & width.

e.g. code that gives you height for multiline label with fixed width of 200px:

```
CGSize textSize = { 
    200.0,   // limit width
    20000.0  // and height of text area
}; 

CGSize size = [descriptionString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGFloat height = size.height < 36? 36: size.height; // lower bound for height

CGRect labelFrame = [myLabel frame];
labelFrame.size.height = height;
[myLabel setFrame:labelFrame];
[myLabel setText:descriptionString];
```